# 404 GET ext.watermark.woff issue (MIME)

Tags: extjs, font-awesome, mime

In my first Extjs project I am getting the following error in browser debug mode.

Can anyone tell me why I am getting this error?

I have added this is my web.config

```
    <staticContent>
  <remove fileExtension=".woff"/>
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/x-font-woff" />
  <remove fileExtension=".woff2"/>
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="application/x-font-woff2" />
</staticContent>
<security>
  <requestFiltering>
    <fileExtensions>
      <add fileExtension=".woff" allowed="true" />
      <add fileExtension=".ttf" allowed="true" />
      <add fileExtension=".woff2" allowed="true" />
    </fileExtensions>
  </requestFiltering>
</security>
```

I have also added to iis
[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you verified the files are where they are supposed to be? If so, your server isn't setup to serve those files correctly, not really an Ext issue.

Comment: How can I tell where they are supposed to be ?

Comment: I'm sure whatever you're looking at in your screenshot has the full path. Check that it matches.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli for the 404 GET ext.watermark.woff?n6lnws error... the request url is http://localhost:57007/Sencha/build/development/ExtApplication4/resources/ext-watermark/fonts/ext-watermark.woff?n6lnws.  Do I literally paste that file in that directory?  I thought extjs was supposed to create the BUILD folder?

Comment: I manually added the files to the folders it was looking for and no more errors.  thanks!!!  question though.. shouldn't sencha app watch put the files where they are needed?  it was missing in the BUILD folder

Comment: AFAIR Ext.watermark is only part of trial versions of ExtJS. Trial versions of extjs are not supposed to be used with Sencha Cmd, so no one found that bug yet. Feel free to file a bug report with Sencha, but I wouldn't, because I guess a question about your license will come up then...